# increasing the precision of finding roots of a polynomial in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a polynomial depends on `x` and `y` in matlab, when I find its roots for different `x`, sometimes substitution of the roots in the polynomial is not an almost zero value, what is the problem?

Comment: What are you using to do root finding in MATLAB? Please post the smallest code segment that exhibits your problem.

Comment: As I said my polynomial depend on two variable x and y. I sweep x and use "sym2poly" function to find the coefficients and then use "roots" function to find roots of those coefficients.

Comment: @user1907354 - your comment is very helpful, but it would **significantly** help your question if you edit it with a small code sample.

Comment: Don't ask the same question multiple times. Do change your first question if it is stated imprecisely. Both of your questions center on the same polynomial, and your misunderstanding of numerical issues in floating point computation.

Answer (score 1):

Numerical issues may arise when `x` and `y` are poorly scaled. If, for example, your root `(x,y)` has very large values, machine precision might prevent you from getting the precise root. Try scale your function to a compact domain around `(0,0)` (usually `[-1,1]x[-1,1]` is a good starting point).

```
%// let mx and my be upper bounds to |x| and |y| respectively
nx = x / mx; %// change of variables
ny = y / my;
%// express your polynom in nx and ny and solve for them
%// let nrx and nry be a root of the polynom in the new changed variables, then:
rx = nrx * mx; %// root in original varialbes
ry = nry * my;
%// if you want to verify that the roots indeed brings your polynom to zero, you should try it in the scaled domain with rnx, rny.
```